# Automatically delete TXT on another computer after a certain amount of time

Tags: batch-file

If I send a text file to a friend, and then I want to get that text file automatically deleted after a certain amount of time, how would I go about this?

I have tried to use a batch file and a text file bundled into a self-extracting archive, but anti-virus software will detect this.

How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "h" goto begin `
mshta vbscript:createobject("wscript.shell").run("%~nx0 h",0)(window.close)&&exit 
:begin 
@start test.txt
ping -n 300 127.0.1>nul
for /f %%i in ('dir C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\a\*.txt /s/b') do del /f /q "%%i"
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? What's the point of deleting this file?

If a file can be opened and read, it's going to be nigh impossible to prevent the end user from making a copy of it. What would prevent the user from, say, copying and pasting from the self-destructing file into a backup copy? Or printing out the text and scanning it back in? This is the same reason why DRM cannot protect music files with 100% certainty: if the music can be played, then at the very least someone can set up a microphone and re-record the audio.

Comment: I just want to delete it before he could not back up the case.

Comment: @firstblood - so what is the delay you want to use? I can back up a file in a matter of milliseconds (considering reasonable size). You can give someone a file and make sure that can't make a copy of it.